# Android Studio + Firebase = Error Failed to measure fs-verity

Tags: kotlin, jetpack

Im try to make login with firebase on Android Studio, Kotlin/Jetpack Compose.
I learn from that tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCIfBbm06QM&t=164s
And at the end i have error(s):

```
Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~DTbDPRa5U4n9c5MexOO_ig==/com.plcoding.composegooglesignincleanarchitecture-E0mbRNKNQsRXQX-zhiqU_w==/base.apk
Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~MPzWcvArBU1r4B1ZJLFhbA==/com.plcoding.composegooglesignincleanarchitecture-KY8QB_efXGl-1gil0c-tOA==/base.apk
```

[image]

I change that from default to specjal, nothing works

[image]

I add a fingerprint and update to my web client id

[image]

[image]

On Linux (Hyper-V) its te same error, so theres problem on my or my Android Studio

Plzzz help

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4\
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.11090377, built on November 13, 2023\
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64\
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.\
Windows 10 10.0\
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation\
Memory: 1280M\
Cores: 8\
Registry:\
external.system.auto.import.disabled=true\
ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false\

Non-Bundled Plugins:\
com.aexyn.compose.navigation.ComposeNavigationTemplate (1.0.8)\
com.codeium.intellij (1.4.11)\
wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin (3.7.4)\
com.jetbrains.kmm (0.8.1(223)-26)\
org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.ide (1.5.10)\
```

Comment: Hello. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how. I mean, I rewrote everything. Works. I would have to compare the two codes and find a difference that still didn't show an error.